Anomalies and SPT phases
There seems to be some connection between anomalies and Symmetry Protected Topological Orders, but I cannot find exact details of what the relation is. My impression is that group cohomology and projective representations are also relevant. My question is: how exactly are these objects connected and are there any comprehensive reviews in the literature to further understand this?

The most clear answer is probably found in this paper by Xiao-Gang Wen.
It is important to note that the "anomalies" present in the discussion are 't Hooft anomalies. These anomalies appear when one has a symmetry group $G$ which is valid as a global symmetry, but which is obstructed from being gauged.
The relationship between the SPT orders and anomalies can be made precise:

An SPT state with symmetry $G$ has a 't Hooft anomaly on its boundary. That is, an attempt to gauge the symmetry group $G$ will yield an anomalous gauge theory on the boundary.

The connection to group cohomology is that anomalies in $d-1$ spatial dimensions are classified by the group $H^{d+2}(G,\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^{d+1}(G,U(1))$, one of the cohomology groups of the group $G.$ So, if one has a $d$-dimensional SPT phase, it will be classified by $H^{d+1}(G,U(1))$, since the $(d-1)$-dimensional boundary has an anomaly.
Projective representations are somewhat more specific. They are a special case, classified by the second cohomology group $H^2(G,U(1))$, so they would classify 1-dimensional SPT phases.

Slight correction. SPTs are classified by $H^{d+1}(G,U(1))$. This is how you properly get that the SPTs in 1d are classified by the projective representations of $G$. In the paper you cited, Wen uses $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong U(1)$

Thank you! I was looking at another paper that noted that in $d$ spacetime dimensions, the equalities hold. I missed this. It seems that the connecting equality is $H^{d+2}(G,\mathbb{Z}) = H^{d+1}(G,U(1)).$ I will make an edit
